# My intent putExtra into two different names with different value. But I get same value in another activity?

Tags: android

I have two names which suppose to get two different string value. Why S0 and S1 all get "ABC"?

DF=""

DWF="ABC"

Alarm.putExtra(com.Md.AlarmReminder.D0, DF);
Alarm.putExtra(com.Md.AlarmReminder.D1, DWF);

In another activity:
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

s0 =extras.getString(com.Md.AlarmReminder.D0);
s1 =extras.getString(com.Md.AlarmReminder.D1);

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved after I changed the initilization of D0 and D1. My original intilization was
D0=""
D1=""

I guess that the pointer gets comfused.